# How can I use Leiningen to build a non clojure/Java system?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am using maven and ant to build some mixed Java/non Java environments. How can I use Leiningen to the same?

### Update

leiningen supports Java and javac. For other systems you can write a plugin

Comment: Create a leiningen plugin that executes your external build command. It's not that hard. See also https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/wiki/Plugins

Comment: I looked at the link you sent. Which plug in from the list should I be looking at?

Comment: I'm implying that you should write your own plugin.

Comment: Ok, thanks, so it is not available out of the box

Comment: Leiningen is a build tool original created for Clojure. Like many build tools (i.e. Make) it can be extended to do anything with some work. Out of the box, it supports Clojure "AOT" compilation and also calling `javac`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I amended my question as I didn\t explain the part that javac is supported